# Double request in Chrome with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, request

I'm doing a test with Nodejs to increment a global counter, according to the scripts below. Everything works, except that Chrome executes two sequential requests when I refresh it, which causes the counter to increment twice as well (see the image). In Postman and Firefox works fine and only one request occurs on refresh. I've done the tests running the app on Linux and Windows and the problem with Chrome holds. Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const rotas = require("./route-test")(app);

const port = 3000;

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, function(){
    console.log('App listening port: ', port);
});
```

**route-test.js**

```
const myGlobalVars = require("./global-vars");

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use('/', (req, res) => {
       res.end('Counter in: ' + myGlobalVars.counter); 
    });

    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        //console.log(req.originalUrl);
    });
}
```

**global-vars.js**

```
let myCounter = 0;

const _myVars = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  dateInit: { 
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: new Date() 
  },
  counter: {
    configurable: false,
    get: function() { return myCounter++ },
    set: function(_val) {
      myCounter = _val;
    }
  }
});

module.exports = _myVars;
```

[image: 2 requests]

Comment: I think you have to provide the source code at the client side.

Comment: There is no source code on the client side. This is a simple test. The code you're seeing is complete and the only information that will be displayed on the client side is `Counter in: XX` ("XX" is the value of the current count).

Answer (score 4):

I check all 3 files... so in FireFox and Google Canary(developers version) we have only 1 request(we got 1 request and we increment only once `myGlobalVars.counter` ). in simple Google Chrome version we have 2 request. one of them is request for favicon.ico.  so we just need to add condition to ignore favicon.ico request and dont increment twice our `myGlobalVars.counter` value...

in **route-test.js**

```
const myGlobalVars = require("./global-vars");

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.use('/', (req, res) => {

  // instead of this code res.end('Counter in: ' + myGlobalVars.counter);
  // add this condition
  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.end( `\n\n\nCounter in: ${myGlobalVars.counter}` );
  }

});


}
```

Comment: The explanation is correct. If you let node.js print out `request.url` you'll see it's asking for favicon. Although I don't necessarily agree with your solution on the `req.url === '/'` part, I upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the request that the browser makes to the server to get `/favicon.ico` resource.

Answer (score 0):

You might have faced this bug :
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810

Today, it should be fixed in Chrome, but you can still reproduce it in Chromium instrumented by puppeteer for example.